# Java how to partition a collection while modifying it

Tags: java, java-8

I have a use case where I want to partition a collection with a specific regex and while partitioning I want to modify each string. If I don't do that I have to iterate through the keys again and do another regex match because I can use regex grouping.

How can I do this in Java 8 ?

Comment: Show some code please

Answer (score 1):

You can make good use of the distinction between `Pattern` and `Matcher` in this situation. For example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[abcd]*");
List<String> results = myStrings.stream()
    .map(pattern::matcher).filter(Matcher::matches)
    .map(matcher -> matcher.replaceAll("replacement"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Matcher `group` could also be used if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain certain Collectors from [java.util.stream.Collectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) in order to make more complicated ones. The following partitions by a Predicate and then *modifies* with a Function. *Though note only the resultant data is modified.*

```
Map<Boolean,List<String>> partitions = strings.stream().collect(
   Collectors.partitioningBy( s -> Pattern.matches(regex,s), //predicate
   Collectors.mapping( s -> modify(x), //function
   Collectors.toList()
   )));
```